# Webforms with offsite payment processor development

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, paypal

Is anyone currently working to resolve the incompatibility between off site payment processors such as paypal standard and webforms?

On the wiki, it states its being developed.

Does any off site payment processor work with webforms yet?

Many thanks all,

Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issues related to paypal standard and webform_civicrm have already been resolved. I've just updated the wiki documentation to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the solution to paypal standard. It's actually paypal express I was after working. Do you know if this is included?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of. We collect data and correct pricing in Webform and pass that to a PHP file to process payment at Stripe (which I highly recommend). I can send you the PHP if interested.

Comment: Stripe and webform_civicrm have been fixed to work together so I'm not sure why you need a custom php script.